# Обработка xml с & (амперсандом)

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть xml (неправильная) в одном из тегов есть

```
<abc>Tom & Jerry</abc>
```

Есть xlst которая тупо копирует xml

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

И обработка падает на этой xml. Как её обработать и заменить `&` амперсанд на `&amp;`?

Comment: Вы сами говорите, что оригинальный «*XML*» вовсе не *XML.*  Так что вам сначала надо обработать изначальные данные, экранировав амперсанды.

Comment: Если вы используете xslt 2.0, то можно открыть файл как простой текст функцией `unparsed-text`. После чего можно попытаться заменить неправильные символы и далее обрабатывать данные уже как xml.

Answer (score 0):

Если символ `&` находится внутри XML, он должен быть следующим: `$amp;`

После этого XSLT будет обрабатывать XML без проблем.

> XML

```
<abc>Tom &amp; Jerry</abc>
```

Comment: Нет такой возможности. Есть задача реализовать это с помощью xslt

Comment: Если вы используете XSLT v.1.0, у вас должен быть правильно сформированный входной XML (well-formed). В противном случае это не XML.И XSLT не может обработать такой беспорядок.